# The argument type 'void Function(String?)?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)? in Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, validation, null

**The Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Color color;
  final Color fillColor;
  final void Function(String?)? onSave;
  final void Function(String?)? validator;

  const CustomTextFormField({
     this.hintText = "",
     this.color = Colors.black,
     this.fillColor = Colors.grey,
     this.onSave ,
     this.validator,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        onSaved: onSave,
        validator: validator,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: color,
          ),
          fillColor: fillColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Problem:
The argument type 'void Function(String?)?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'

Q: Why there an error at this point below:
***validator: validator***

Comment: It needs a return value. What’s it gonna do with “no return value”? So have to use a compatible signature, possibly wrapping the original to provide a dummy value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validator is a type of

```
typedef FormFieldValidator<in T> = String? Function(T? value)
```

so for the validator, you need to use

```
final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
```

Complete code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Color color;
  final Color fillColor;
  final void Function(String?)? onSave;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;

  const CustomTextFormField({
     this.hintText = "",
     this.color = Colors.black,
     this.fillColor = Colors.grey,
     this.onSave ,
     this.validator,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        onSaved: onSave,
        validator: validator,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: color,
          ),
          fillColor: fillColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```